# Invisible Captcha timestamp threshold not triggering with Devise confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, invisible-recaptcha

Today I've had about 10 bot accounts created on my Rails 7 app hosted on fly.io!

I feel I've followed all the steps to install and configure the invisible captcha gem but I can't get the timeout to trigger with a 400 second timestamp threshold.

I am able using the confirmable option with Devise where the users are sent a link to confirm their accounts before they can access the site.

I am using TomSelect JS to allow new users to choose a role when creating a new account, not sure if that's affecting anything.

When I inspect my sign up form I am able to see the hidden field that is generated with the  `<%= invisible_captcha %>`:

```
<div class="akycjhmgilspxv_1669858439"><style media="screen">.akycjhmgilspxv_1669858439 {position:absolute!important;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;}</style><label for="akycjhmgilspxv">How often do you go out dancing?</label><input type="text" name="akycjhmgilspxv" id="akycjhmgilspxv" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1"><input type="hidden" name="spinner" id="spinner" value="0427cfe9c26b1956983b7f12163dbb94" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

My routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  devise_scope :user do
    match '/register.user', to: 'devise/registrations#create', via: :post
  end
```

My config/intializers/invisible_captcha.rb, note the timestamp threshold of 400!

```
InvisibleCaptcha.setup do |config|
        # config.honeypots           << ['more', 'fake', 'attribute', 'names']
        # config.visual_honeypots    = false
        config.timestamp_threshold = 400
        # config.timestamp_enabled   = true
        # config.injectable_styles   = false
        # config.spinner_enabled     = true
      
        # Leave these unset if you want to use I18n (see below)
        config.sentence_for_humans     = 'How often do you go out dancing?'
        config.timestamp_error_message = 'Something went wrong, please try again.'
      end
```

And my registrations controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  invisible_captcha only: [:create]
```

I am making sure that I restart my server with all these changes but I'm still able to create an account even though the timestamp threshold is at 400.

Should I just hope the bots fill out the hidden field each time?